# How many days does it take to get a tourist visa to Spain and a transit visa to the USA

Tags: usa, transit-visas, spain, tourist-visas

I am about to apply for a tourist visa to Spain. According to their website, I have all the documents needed. Can I please ask how many days does it normally take to get a visa?

As I need a transit visa from the USA government as well, how many days does it take to get one?

I will apply for both visas from New Zealand.

Comment: As for Spain, It shouldn't take more than 2-3 weeks (talking from my experience), and for USA I can't really say, haven't done it before, but I've heard that is really fast, something like 2-4 days.

Comment: Did you already book the flight? There are many NZ<->Europe connections that do not need a US transit visa. As the processing fees for US visa are quite high, it may in total be cheaper for you to take one of the middle-east or Asian airlines.

Comment: Are you traveling on a New Zealand passport?

Comment: @choster most probably not

Comment: @choster blackbird is right. I am not travelling with a NZ passport.

Comment: @DCTLib, thanks, I will look into it. That is new info. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spanish [embassy](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/WELLINGTON/es/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Paginas/VisadosUniformeSchengen.aspx) in Wellington says they usually process regular Schengen applications within 15 days, sometimes extending to 30.

> El plazo máximo para resolver los expedientes de solicitud de visado de corta duración (Schengen) es de 15 días naturales a partir de la fecha de presentación de la solicitud. Este plazo podrá ampliarse a un máximo de 30 días naturales en casos concretos
>
> *The deadline for resolving application files of short-term visa (Schengen) is 15 calendar days from the date of filing of the application. This period may be extended up to 30 calendar days in individual cases*

The US [page](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/nz/nz-niv-waittimeinfo.asp#processing) for New Zealand (presumably for Wellington) says they process nonimmigrant applications within 5-7 business days, but that's after the interview, for which there's currently a day [waiting time](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html/).

> Although visa processing time is typically five (5) to seven (7)
> business days, processing time for specific cases may vary due to an
> individual's circumstances and other special requirements, and this
> may take a longer time. Visa processing cannot be expedited.

Note that while the US has its embassy in [Wellington](https://www.usembassy.gov/east-asia.html), that page for the interview wait times has times for Auckland. Also, these mean processing times also assume you have a complete and ready application.